# Django-wkhtmltopdf returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf

I'm receiving the following error using `wkhtmltopdf` in a Django project in development.  If I try and run it using an Apache server the status code returned is 6 rather than 1.

> Command '['wkhtmltopdf', '--disable-javascript', '--encoding',
>   u'utf8', '--quiet', u'False', '/tmp/wkhtmltopdfnUwu3t.html', '-']'
>   returned non-zero exit status 1

This is my view.

```
class MyPDF(OrgOwnerMixin, PDFTemplateView):
    filename = 'my_pdf.pdf'
    template_name = 'pdf/test.html'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Organisation.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(MyPDF, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        ctx['object'] = self.get_object()
        return ctx
```

And here is the Traceback:

Traceback:

```
File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/fargus/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/fargus/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/fargus/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/fargus/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  107.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/fargus/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/views.py" in rendered_content
  78.             cmd_options=cmd_options

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/fargus/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py" in render_pdf_from_template
  186.                           cmd_options=cmd_options)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/fargus/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py" in convert_to_pdf
  124.     return wkhtmltopdf(pages=filename, **cmd_options)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/fargus/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py" in wkhtmltopdf
  110.     return check_output(ck_args, **ck_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py" in check_output
  574.         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)

Exception Type: CalledProcessError at /pdf/org-1/
Exception Value: Command '['wkhtmltopdf', '--disable-javascript', '--encoding', u'utf8', '--quiet', u'False', '/tmp/wkhtmltopdfEG5K8j.html', '-']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the command 
`wkhtmltopdf --disable-javascript --encoding utf8 --quiet False /tmp/wkhtmltopdfEG5K8j.html -`

And see the error you get.

Comment: This is the route I took.  I found I needed to reinstall `wkhtmltopdf` using `wget` with `pathced QT` rather that `apt get`, then include `--allow /tmp` in the options and then change my `style.css` file.  I haven't found the issue with my original file but changed formatting so it works

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, but it was due to my template linking to external files. I found that the solution was to add `'enable-local-file-access': True` to my options:

```
cmd_options = {'quiet': None, 'enable-local-file-access': True}
```

See: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4460

Answer (score 1):

By seeing `PDFTemplateView` I suspect that you're using [django-wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf/).

Have a look at the `Exception Value` of your traceback:

```
Exception Value: Command '['wkhtmltopdf', '--disable-javascript', '--encoding', u'utf8', '--quiet', u'False', '/tmp/wkhtmltopdfEG5K8j.html', '-']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I see a suspicious parameter `False` here: `--quiet False /tmp/wkhtmltopdfEG5K8j.html`

However, I just did a fresh installation (latest Django 2.x and `django-wkhtmltopdf==3.1.0`) and I could not reproduce your issue. **BUT** I noticed one thing: You're inheriting your `MyPDF` class from `OrgOwnerMixin`, which you forgot to post here.

I suspect that either in `OrgOwnerMixin` OR in any class that `OrgOwnerMixin` inherits from (if there's any) you have put something like:

```
class OrgOwnerMixin:
    cmd_options = {'quiet': False}
```

This causes `False` to be passed as an argument to the `--quiet` flag in the command line, and in consequence - triggers your exception.

If you want to disable the `--quiet` flag, you have to do:

```
cmd_options = {'quiet': None}
```

Although I don't see this pointed out in the documentation, I can clearly see in the code that only if you pass `None` as the value of an options it gets removed from the commandline. You can check this by looking at the [`wkhtmltopdf.utils._options_to_args`](https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py#L52) function.

Answer (score 0):

Running the command showed me what the error was. In my case it was that I didn't have a static/ folder. Running `python3 manage.py collectstatic` fixed that.